# sql group has no more than 2 distinct specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, self-join

I have a table 
Raw data is like

```
RollNumber | Subject | G         | Part | Status  
------------------------------------------------  
1          | 1       | 1         | 1    |  1  
1          | 1       | 1         | 2    |  1  
1          | 2       | 1         | 1    |  1  
1          | 2       | 1         | 2    |  5  
1          | 3       | 1         | 1    |  1  
1          | 3       | 1         | 2    |  1  
2          | 1       | 2         | 1    |  1  
2          | 1       | 2         | 2    |  1  
2          | 2       | 2         | 1    |  1  
2          | 2       | 2         | 2    |  1  
2          | 3       | 2         | 1    |  1  
2          | 3       | 2         | 2    |  1 
3          | 1       | 2         | 1    |  1  
3          | 1       | 2         | 2    |  1  
3          | 2       | 2         | 1    |  1  
3          | 2       | 2         | 2    |  1  
3          | 3       | 2         | 1    |  0  
3          | 3       | 2         | 2    |  1
4          | 1       | 2         | 1    |  1  
4          | 1       | 2         | 2    |  1  
4          | 2       | 2         | 1    |  1  
4          | 2       | 2         | 2    |  1  
4          | 3       | 2         | 1    |  3  
4          | 3       | 2         | 2    |  1
```

i want all RollNumber data which should have distinct status 1 and 3
my required  data is like :

```
RollNumber | Subject | G         | Part | Status  
------------------------------------------------ 
4          | 1       | 2         | 1    |  1  
4          | 1       | 2         | 2    |  1  
4          | 2       | 2         | 1    |  1  
4          | 2       | 2         | 2    |  1  
4          | 3       | 2         | 1    |  3  
4          | 3       | 2         | 2    |  1
```

i need a query which is applicable on all  sql like also on mysql

Comment: mysql  or sql-server ?

Comment: @scaisEdge both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation to find the rollnumbers that have both 1, 3 as status in subquery and use that to get all the relevant rows.

Using `IN`:

```
select *
from t
where rollnumber in (
        select rollnumber
        from t
        where status in (1, 3)
        group by rollnumber
        having count(distinct status) = 2
        );
```

Using `JOIN`:

```
select t1.*
from t t1
join (
    select rollnumber
    from t
    where status in (1, 3)
    group by rollnumber
    having count(distinct status) = 2
    ) t2 on t1.rollnumber = t2.rollnumber;
```

The subquery filters to keep only the rows with status 1 or 3 using a where clause. Then while grouping on rollNumber, we check if distinct status count is 2, which means both 1 and 3 are present for that rollNumber.

Comment: The `join` is probably much better on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use HAVING and GROUP BY clause to get rollnumber having status 1 and 3 and finally join to get result.

CREATE TABLE #table(RollNumber INT, Subject INT, G INT,Part INT, Status INT)
INSERT INTO #table(RollNumber , Subject , G ,Part , Status )
SELECT 1          , 1       , 1         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1          , 1       , 1         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1          , 2       , 1         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1          , 2       , 1         , 2    ,  5  UNION ALL
SELECT 1          , 3       , 1         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1          , 3       , 1         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 2          , 1       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 2          , 1       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 2          , 2       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 2          , 2       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 2          , 3       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 2          , 3       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 3          , 1       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 3          , 1       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 3          , 2       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 3          , 2       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 3          , 3       , 2         , 1    ,  0  UNION ALL
SELECT 3          , 3       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 4          , 1       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 4          , 1       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 4          , 2       , 2         , 1    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 4          , 2       , 2         , 2    ,  1  UNION ALL
SELECT 4          , 3       , 2         , 1    ,  3  UNION ALL
SELECT 4          , 3       , 2         , 2    ,  1

SELECT *
FROM #table T
JOIN 
(
   SELECT RollNumber 
   FROM #table
   WHERE Status IN (1,3)
   GROUP BY RollNumber 
   HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT Status) = 2
 )A ON A.RollNumber = T.RollNumber
```